# Libreswan IPSec IKEv2 unable to connect to multiple remote IPs

Tags: ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, libreswan

I have been beating my head against this for awhile, and I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a number of IPSec tunnels established, mostly from libreswan (v3.23) on CentOS to Cisco ASAs. Most are IKE v1, and in that case if I want to reach multiple hosts on the remote side I can have a formulation like this in my .conf file:

```
conn test1
rightsubnet=192.168.1.111/255.255.255.255
rightsourceip=192.168.1.111
also=test_common
auto=start
conn test2
rightsubnet=192.168.1.112/255.255.255.255
rightsourceip=192.168.1.112
also=test_common
auto=start
```

However, if I use this syntax with IKEv2 (ikev2=insist), I can start test1 and reach 192.168.1.111, but test2 will then not complete; or I can start test2 and test1 won't work.

My question is, what syntax will allow me to establish an IKEv2 tunnel which lets me reach both 192.168.1.111 & 192.168.1.112?

I have tried using:

```
conn test
rightsubnet=192.168.1.96/27
leftsubnet=192.168.2.2/32
also=test_common
auto=start
```

This formulation gets me up to the point where I see "STATE_PARENT_I2: sent v2I2, expected v2R2" but then all I get is "STATE_PARENT_I2: retransmission".

Similarly, I have tried:

```
conn test
rightsubnets=192.168.1.111/32,192.168.1.112/32
leftsubnet=192.168.2.2/32
also=test_common
auto=start
```

Using the rightsubnets directive causes the connection to not start, even if a single range is specified.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Edit: I have discovered that I can use the rightsubnets directive; however it will only start the first tunnel. The syntax which works is:

```
rightsubnets={192.168.1.111/32 192.168.1.112/32}
```

In this example, 192.168.1.111 is reachable, but the second address gets to "STATE_V2_CREATE_I: sent IPsec Child req wait response" and never completes.

Answer (score 1):

Change `leftsubnet` to `leftsubnets`

```
rightsubnets={192.168.1.111/32,192.168.1.112/32}
leftsubnets={192.168.2.2/32}
```

Also in my case this only works if `right` is not `%any` with IKEv2.